# Replace multiple fields in a column, not characters but words, in R

Tags: r, data

I have a dataframe with some thousands of entries each, I've different province names. I need to substitute these names (which are repeated) for others.

Quick example, I have this column (I don't know how to show it like a column here):

```
**Provincia**   Álava Álava Albacete Albacete Albacete ... Zaragoza Zaragoza
```

And I need to change for:

```
**Provincia**
ALAVA_1
ALAVA_1
ALBACETE_1
ALBACETE_1
ALBACETE_1
...
ZGZ_1
ZGZ_1
```

I've tried the following:

old_names <- unique (df$Provincias)

> Álava Albacete ... Zaragoza

new_names <- c ("ALAVA_1", "ALBACETE_1",... "ZGZ_1")

df$Provincias <- gsub (old_names, new_names, df$Provincias)

> ALAVA_1 ALAVA_1 Albacete Albacete Albacete ... Zaragoza
>
> 1: In gsub (new_names, old_names, df$Provincias) :
>     argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
> 2: In gsub (new_names, old_names, df$Provincias) :
>     argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So it only changes the first term (Álava for ALAVA_1) all the times, but it doesn't change the rest of Provincias

Of course I know that I can do this one by one, for the 52 provinces, but then I have more dataframes to do the same... I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please edit your question to include how this has a spatial component relevant to GIS SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shamelessly stealing this from [Map Values and Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323410/map-values-and-replace#18323600), you can do it like this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("Alava", "Alava", 
            "Albacete","Albacete", "Albacete", 
            "Zaragoza", "Zaragoza"))
colnames(df) <- c("Provincias")
newnames <- c("ALAVA_1", "ALBACETE_1", "ZGZ_1")
oldnames <- unique(df$Provincias)
# create mapping (assuming "newnames" are in the same order as "oldnames"; 
# you can achieve this by sorting the vectors, if necessary)
map <- setNames(newnames, oldnames)
# apply mapping (1 means that you are mapping the first column)
new_df <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 1, function(x) map[as.character(x)]))
colnames(new_df) <- colnames(df)
# check result
df
new_df
```

Comment: it seems that it works, i had to change some details because my dataframe has 20k lines and 9 columns, but the "new_df" line is what I needed, cool (and yes, newnames are in same order as oldnames, so perfect!)

Comment: @manup - Great to hear. In that case, please accept the answer to close the question and to indicate to others that this is the solution